# Issue with Swift code to make recognition app

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

**hello everyone ... I am trying to make an app recognition, simply I have an image view, text view and button and code is below .. my first issue is that my imageview isnt changing after picking a picture! .. my second issue that it tells me that  "Arguments label image1 do not match any available overloads "
any help pls ?

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class  ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var myimage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var info: UITextView!

    @IBAction func Import(_ sender: Any) {
        // create image picker
        let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagepicker.delegate=self
        imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(imagepicker ,animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }

      func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let Image1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            myimage.image = Image1   
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // detect function
    func detect(){
        let image2 = CIImage (Image1:myimage.image!)! 

       // issue is here it says 
       "Arguments label image1 do not match any available overloads "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue:** Looks like your delegate method declaration doesn't match the one in the protocol, so it's treated as a separate method. Xcode even gives a warning:

> Instance method 'imagePickerController(picker:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

Try changing this line:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
```

to:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

**UPD:** please also read @dfd's comments below on how to avoid this (quite a common) type of confusion.

---

**Second issue:** as already mentioned by others, you should pass the parameter as the initialiser properly. With minimum changes to your code it will be:

```
let image2 = CIImage (image: myimage.image!)!
```

However, the less exclamation marks (i.e. force unwrapping) the better; for more info on that, check [Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID246).

Comment: Additional piece of help, regards to first question - this was a change IIRC from Swift 2 to Swift 3. The Swift language, currently using 4.x (probably 4.1) has undergone *significant* changes. Probably the largest was between 2.x to 3.x back in September 2015 (again, my memory is a bit hazy). Please be aware that most "copy/paste" code that uses Swift 2 will likely contain either syntax errors or - in your case - a delegate method that has a signature change....

Comment: (Splitting this out because I intend to emphasize it.) The easiest thing you can do to correct this is "let the Xcode editor do your work", or use auto complete! Declare your delegate, let Xcode "fix" any required methods, then add any optional methods using auto complete. (And of course, come post-WWDC time when the *next* version of both UIKit and Swift are in beta, test!)

Comment: Very good point. And what Xcode currently suggests as a fix-it for the above warning is "make your method private" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Perhaps another option could be to "use the protocol's method declaration", and perhaps that way the developer would have to choose between two options consciously.

Comment: man you are just great ! knowing exactly what the problem is! thank you so much brother

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are missing the `_` in your delegate call, just before `picker:`  and you need to write `Any` instead of `AnyObject`. It should be:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) { //... }
```

Second problem, your function needs to be written like this:

```
let image2 = CIImage(image: myimage.image!)
```

Comment: yes it worked ! thank u so much ... but about the first issue, when i import a picture my imageview isnt changing do u have any advice ?

Comment: I've found your problem.  I'll update my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

This error because you have write error label

> CIImage.init(image: <#T##UIImage#>)

you can do it like this

```
    guard  let image = myimage.image  else {
            return
        }
let image2 = CIImage.init(image: image)
```